# How do I remove Slony from a restored PostgreSQL database?

Tags: replication, postgresql

I've restored a database which came from a server on which Slony was running. The server on which the database has been restored does not have Slony installed.

When the database restored, there were a lot of errors reported, with Slony related objects not getting created due to Slony related logins being missing. This I thought was not a problem, as losing the Slony objects didn't seem to matter, and infact seemed desirable.

However, now I've got an anoying, if not critical problem. Whenever one clicks on a table in the newly restored DB in PGAdmin, a Slony related error popup ... pops up.

The first one reads:
"An error has occured: ERROR: function _rmscl.getlocalnodeid(unknown) does not exist"

I notice that under the Replication node in PGAdmin, that there is a Slony replication cluster. Trying to drop this cluster results in more object missing type errors.

Does anyone have any ideas how we can remove the last vestiges of Slony from this database?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you don't have a `slon` daemon running anymore, just drop the schema that was installed by Slony:

```
DROP SCHEMA _replication CASCADE;
```

(Adjust the name.)