# Clean DB from Slony objects

Tags: postgresql, replication, slony

I have old DB server Postgres 8.4 and Slony (slave, to which only a table replicates)

I'm trying to migrate to new server with Postgres 9.x without slony and slony deamon, I would later setup other replication.

My plan is:

 1. OLD DB: pg_dumpall -U --clean > dump.sql

 2. NEW DB: psql -U < dump.sql

 I have some errors during migration, but it looks like errors due to the lack of SLONY on new server.

 Is it correct? Can I ignore them? 

 3. Delete all objects related to SLONY to have a clean database, only with data.

 How to do it?

I found [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/220901/how-do-i-remove-slony-from-a-restored-postgresql-database) but I am not sure it describes every operation that should be done.

To sum up: **I need help how to recover the database so that it is clean, without SLONY objects.**

Comment: It's been a long time since I did anything with slony, but if I remember correctly the slony stuff is in a different schema, so you need to figure out how to tell pg_dumpall to skip the slony schema (whatever it is called).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slony add schema, but not only..

 Slony adds its own sequence as an extra column to tables without a primary key.

 To have a clean database, you must remove all these objects.

I found solution: http://lists.slony.info/pipermail/slony1-general/2008-April/007906.html

I was able to migrate to a server without a Slony without errors.

The problem I encountered was the script from the attachment refused to read the name and I had to hardcoded "cluster_name".

**UPDATE:**

Answer from Slony FAQ: 
http://slony.info/documentation/1.2/faq.html#AEN6892

SLONIK TABLE ADD KEY / SLONIK TABLE DROP KEY

> This command was introduced in Slony-I 1.0
>
> In Slony-I version 2.0, this command is removed as obsolete because
>   triggers are no longer "messed around with" in the system catalogue.